# Chrome shows a CORS error when api request payload is too big

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, iis

I have a React app that's making a call to an ASP.NET api running in IIS. The API call is made using the fetch() api. It looks like this:

```
let response = await fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  credentials: 'include',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(data)
});
```

My problem is that if the payload is too large, I see an immediate CORS error in the Chrome dev tools' Network tab. The payload in question is a list of about 50,000 IDs, each one 10 characters long (So I guess this request is probably about ~500KB in size based on that math).

My question is, where is this payload limit coming from? The Server? I checked the web.config file, but didn't see anything like "maxRequestLength" in there.

```
//no "maxRequestLength" attribute in web.config
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
```

Comment: Can you post the exact CORS error message?  A screenshot of the network tab in Chrome dev tools would be good as well.

Comment: There are several settings involved, and each has a default value if not present in config file, https://www.textcontrol.com/blog/2019/12/20/documentviewer-configuring-aspnet-for-larger-requests/#:~:text=ASP.NET%20has%20its%20own,2%2C147%2C483%2C647%20kilobytes%20(~82%20Terabyte).

Comment: I faced similar problem. In my case, I was using tinymce (wysiwyg editor) with reactJS. It failed with immediate CORS error when posting data (without receiving any request at backend). The problem only happend when any img tags with specific path are contained in the editor. Anyway it solved by setting `document_base_url` on tinymce setting. Confusing behavior though.

Comment: same error when string content is larger than 30 mb, works fine if below